# How many simple graphs of $n$ vertices are there having no vertices of degree one and no two vertices of degree two share an edge?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

How many simple, connected graphs of $n$ vertices are there having no vertices of degree one and no two vertices of degree exactly two sharing an edge?

My thoughts?  I thought this described the triangulations of an $n-$gon, so if the vertices were labelled, it would give us the ($n-2)^{th}$ Catalan number as the answer.  But Especially Lime has shown it includes some additional graphs; so there will be more graphs than the $(n-2)^{th}$ Catalan number.

Comment: If two vertices have degree $> 2$, are they allowed to share an edge? And generally, do you have any thoughts on a possible solution?

Comment: Are these labelled or unlabelled graphs? (For example if $n=4$ you must have either $5$ or $6$ edges; is the answer $7$ because there are $6$ possible edges you can be missing, and $1$ way to be missing no edges? Or is the answer $2$ because all the graphs you get by removing a single edge are isomorphic?)

Comment: @Stefan good point... fixed.  I'll add my thoughts to the question.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime I was initially interested in the labeled graphs as I'm studying a permutations problem; and the possibility of unlabelled ones had slipped my mind.  But the unlabelled ones are of interest too.  I think the conditions are sufficient to describe the triangulations of an n-gon.

Comment: These aren't only the triangulations of an $n$-gon because any graph you get by adding extra edges to a triangulation meets your criteria. They also include some graphs that don't even *contain* a triangulation of an $n$-gon: eg for $n=7$ take two $4$-vertex triangulations and join them at a single vertex.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime good point. There's one more condition required to make the graph match and I'm not sure how to write it... something like that the graph put have a perimeter which you can travel without going along the same edge twice.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime is the rule... no vertices of degree one and exactly one vertex of degree two?